# When will kill PID fail?

Tags: bash, kill

I'm trying to `kill 31216 31617`,but after **10** times,that process still survives.

Why?

Is there a way to force it dead?

```
root     31216     1  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /root/nginx-1.0.2/objs/nginx -c /root/nginx-1.0.2/conf/nginx.conf
nobody   31217 31216  0 10:49 ?        00:00:00 [nginx] <defunct>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [man](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?kill) page:

> The command kill sends the
> specified signal to the specified
> process or    process group.  If no
> signal is specified, the  TERM  signal
> is  sent.    The  TERM  signal  will
> kill processes which do not catch this
> signal.    For other processes, it may
> be necessary to use the  KILL  (9)
> signal,    since this signal cannot be
> caught.

---

> On Unix and Unix-like computer
> operating systems, **a zombie process or
> defunct process** is a process that has
> completed execution but still has an
> entry in the process table. This entry
> is still needed to allow the process
> that started the (now zombie) process
> to read its exit status. The term
> zombie process derives from the common
> definition of zombie—an undead person.
> In the term's metaphor, the child
> process has "died" but has not yet
> been "reaped". Also, unlike normal
> processes, the kill command has no
> effect on a zombie process.

Source : [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)

---

**EDIT**:

> To **remove** zombies from a system, the
> **SIGCHLD signal** can be sent to the
> parent manually, using the kill
> command. If the parent process still
> refuses to reap the zombie, the next
> step would be to remove the parent
> process. When a process loses its
> parent, init becomes its new parent.
> Init periodically executes the wait
> system call to reap any zombies with
> init as parent.

Source : [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)

Comment: @John,so there's nothing can be done to kill defunc process?

Comment: @locale: yes. it's already dead.Stop the Parent process(31216).

Comment: I want it to disappear,though:(

Comment: @locale: can you kill the parent process? `kill -9 31216`

Comment: @John ,yes it's already kill.

Comment: @locale: see my updated answer from wiki. `SIGCHLD` value is 17( check `kill -l`)

Comment: @locale: then `init` has become the parent process. so `kill -17 1` may help you.

Answer (score 3):

When you are killing a process with a `kill pid`, you are sending a SIGTERM.  Sometimes a process is stuck in a state where it won't listen to signals.  When that happens, try `kill -9 pid` and that will probably kill it for good.

In this case, the defunct process (31217) won't be able to be killed, but the parent process (31216) should die and take its child process with it.

Comment: now the parent process is dead,but the child is still there...

Answer (score 2):

A process currently in an uninterruptible system call (e.g. running kernel code) can't be killed. You can use strace or a similar tool to find out where it is so that you can try to unwedge it.

Comment: I even can't attch to the defunc process,`strace -p 31217` gives me `attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted`

Comment: Even when you attach as root?

Comment: Yes,I'm running it as root.

Comment: Then you're SOL. This process is beyond gone.